# How do I release properties that are added at runtime in a category?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Given the following category definition how might I handle -dealloc both with and without ARC? I am currently using ARC and to the best of my knowledge and poking around in Instruments, the properties are being cleaned up but I am not 100% confident in that.

```
@interface NSObject (SuperUsefulThingIWishAllNSObjectsHad)
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *foo;
@end

#import <objc/runtime.h>
@implementation NSObject (SuperUsefulThingIWishAllNSObjectsHad)
static const void *MyPropertyKey = &MyPropertyKey;
@dynamic foo;
- (NSString *)foo
{
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self,
                                    MyPropertyKey);
}

- (void)setFoo:(NSString *)foo
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self,
                             MyPropertyKey,
                             foo,
                             OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY);
}
```

This is more for my own edification but if the solution isn't *too* hacky I may have some places I actually want to use this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special in `dealloc` to “clean up” an associated object.  The runtime takes care of it for you.  This is independent of ARC.

If you're *not* using ARC, you need to be sure to call `[super dealloc]` in your own `dealloc` overrides.  But you need to do that regardless of your use of associated objects, and the compiler will warn you if you forget.

#### UPDATE

In response to your comment: You're right that the Objective-C Runtime Reference doesn't explicitly say the associated object is released (if appropriate based on the association policy) when the main object is deallocated.  But that is the only reasonable action, because the point of an associated object is to attach a subordinate object to a main object *without changing the main object's source code*.

Anyway, the source code of the Objective-C runtime is open source, so we can inspect it to verify that this is indeed what's implemented.

Look at [`NSObject.mm`](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532.2/runtime/NSObject.mm) and you'll see that `-[NSObject dealloc]` calls `_objc_rootDealloc`, which calls `object_dispose`.

The `object_dispose` function is in [`objc-runtime-new.mm`](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532.2/runtime/objc-runtime-new.mm), and it calls `objc_destructInstance`, which calls `_object_remove_assocations`.

The `_object_remove_assocations` function (yes, it has a typo in the source code) is in [`objc-references.mm`](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532.2/runtime/objc-references.mm).  It removes all objects associated with the object being deallocated, releasing them if appropriate.  If you look at `objc_removeAssociatedReferences`, which is part of the public API and is defined in [`objc-runtime.m`](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532.2/runtime/objc-runtime.mm), you 'll see that it also calls `_object_remove_assocations`.

Comment: So basically whether I'm in ARC or not, objc_set/getAssociatedObject will know how to clean themselves up automatically? Is there any relevant documentation on that? Nothing's jumping out at me https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html .